# OSMdroid - actual position showing north?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using OSMdroid 3.0.4. When using this:

```
    mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);//
    mMyLocationOverlay.setLocationUpdateMinDistance(5);
    mMyLocationOverlay.setLocationUpdateMinTime(5000);
    mMyLocationOverlay.setDrawAccuracyEnabled(true);
    mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    mMyLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
```

enableCompass() fives mi compass in the top left corner of the screen. But when I have my position acquired and I am going some way, my position is showing me an arrow which is pointing to the north, instead of way I am actually going. Why so? Any ideas, how to change this behaviour?

Thx